# Why does minicom configuration always connects on /dev/ttyUSB1?

Tags: minicom

I seem to have a config issue with minicom I haven't seen before. When I start minicom I get this:

```
james@dev2-NUC5i7RYH:/etc/minicom$ minicom
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB1: No such file or directory
```

I'd go ahead and set the usb port to /dev/ttyUSB0 because i removed /dev/ttyUSB1 and save it to the dfl file in:

```
/etc/minicom/minirc.dfl
```

Contents are now:

```
# Machine-generated file - use "minicom -s" to change parameters.
pu port             /dev/ttyUSB0
pu baudrate         19200
pu rtscts           No
```

When then when I exit and restart minicom it continues to connect on port:
/dev/ttyUSB1

```
james@dev2-NUC5i7RYH:/etc/minicom$ minicom
```

Why? What did I do wrong?